# Indefinite integral $\int x\ln|x+1|dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

My solution to check:

$\int x\ln|x+1|dx = $

$u = \ln|x+1|, u' = \frac{1}{x+1}$

$v' = x, v = \frac{x^2}{2}$

$= \frac{1}{2}x^2\ln|x+1|-\frac{1}{2} \int\frac{x^2}{x+1}$

I believe that $\frac{x^2}{x+1}$ can be solved using long division which I don't fully understand. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you substitute $u=x+1$ and change $x$ in terms of $u$, you will get $(u-1)^2 /u$. You can then expand the numerator and apply the fraction rule so you integrate each term on its own.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the wrong way to go; let:
$$I=\int x\ln(|x+1|)\ dx$$
Integrating by parts with $u=x$ and $dv=\ln(|x+1|)\ dx$ yields:
$$I=x((x+1)\ln(|x+1|)-x-1)-\int (x+1)\ln(|x+1|)-x-1\ dx+C$$
Which re-arranges to yield:
$$I=x(x+1)\ln(|x+1|)-x^2-x-\left(I+\int\ln(|x+1|)-x-1\ dx\right)+C$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow I=x(x+1)\ln(|x+1|)-x^2-x-\left(I+\ln(|x+1|)(x+1)-x-1-\frac{x^2}{2}-x\right)+C$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 2I=\ln(|x+1|)(x+1)(x-1)-\frac{x^2}{2}+x+C$$
Dividing both sides by 2 will yield the correct answer without the necessity of of using long division.

Comment: Integration from Limits $-1 \to 0$  results in $\frac{3}{4}$, the given end result does not satisfy this answer.

Comment: This is merely an anti-derivative of the function, which is what we're looking for. Although another answer has found another solution that probably satisfies that particular end result.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$\begin{align*}
x^2 &= a(x+1)^2 + b(x+1) + c \\
&= ax^2 + (2a+b)x + a+b+c
\end{align*} \\[3ex]
\implies (a,b,c)=(1,-2,1)$$

so the quotient resolves to

$$\frac{x^2}{x+1} = \frac{(x+1)^2-2(x+1)+1}{x+1} = (x+1)-2 + \frac1{x+1}$$

and hence

$$\int \frac{x^2}{x+1} \, dx = \frac{x^2}2 - x + \ln|x+1|+C$$